# Android alarm does not fire after reboot:

Tags: android, android-alarms

**EDIT: Anyone who stumbles upon this might want to know, that to fire the alarm after reboot, you need to register it in the Manifest and not runtime.**

I have the following class which I have designed using guidelines from [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    BroadcastReceiver br;
    TextView t; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setup(); 
        t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);


        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 22); // Particular minute
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000*60*60*24, alarmIntent);
    }


    public void setup() {
        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Rise and Shine!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Invoke the service here Put the wake lock and initiate bind service
                t.setText("Hello Alarm set");
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.testrtc") );
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.testrtc"),
                0 );
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have a SampleBootReceiver class which is:

```
public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    BroadcastReceiver br;
    TextView t; 

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Hello from Bootloader", 10000).show();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 22); // Particular minute
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
             alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
             alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        1000*60*60*24, alarmIntent);


        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testrtc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.testrtc.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".SampleBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The alarm is working fine before restart, after reboot I get the toast message from BootReceiver class too. But the Alarm don't reset. Here I want to clarify one point, as the Docs state that the alarm wont be reset unless the app is started at least once by the user: `Set the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in your application's manifest. This allows your app to receive the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED that is broadcast after the system finishes booting (this only works if the app has already been launched by the user at least once):` What is the context of this statement? If the user has to restart the app, anyway the onCreate will be called and the alarm will be set again. Or does this statement mean that throughout the life-cycle, the app has to run on the phone at least once?

Comment: for all API level this problem occurs..??

Comment: I have not tested on API level 19, however this problem is there for Jelly Bean.

Comment: that the thing i was thinking i had faced same thing in JellyBean and i found that BroadcastListener is not working above 4.0 automatically after boot so i had created a service to run my Broadcast.

Comment: In my case the broadcast is working just fine, however the alarm is not reset, as I said I get the toast message from the SampleBootReceiver Class upon reboot. However I lose the alarm.

Answer (score 1):

I Think, you Alarm work fine but i do not call setup() method when your SampleBootReceiver start again , after boot complete.

added this line again in `SampleBootReceiver` to get `alarmIntent`

```
 registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.testrtc") );
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.testrtc"),
                0 );
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
```

Thanks

Comment: But I think I can only define an onReceive (For an alarm), in a class that extends Activity.

Comment: you use new IntentFilter("com.testrtc") to start some thing, you need to call again to do this work.

Comment: How to do that, can you give me a detailed example?

Comment: I get this when I try to add the lines: The method registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter) is undefined for the type SampleBootReceiver

Comment: Please Search ""Why registerReceiver is not work without activity".. you found solution.

Comment: So do I use the context which I get in `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` of the BootReceiver class, how safe is that?

Comment: The app is crashing after reboot.